# CodeTwo Exchange Sync, contact birtday not added to user calendar

Tags: calendar, exchange-server, contacts

I'm using Exchange Sync from CodeTwo. It syncs contacts fine but the birthday set on some contacts is not being added to the end-users calendar.

TROUBLESHOOTING ALREADY DONE:
- Added the Exchange Sync service user to the calendar and gave it rights to create and so forth. No change = No change.
- If I open a synced contact, pretend to change the birthday date (just clicking on the same data again) -> then save the contact, the birthday is added to the calendar.
- Also tried giving rights to the "Standard" and "Anonymous" users = No change.
- Looked through CodeTwo's website. No forum and nothing in their FAQ.
- Manually creating a contact and setting a birthday and this birthday is added to ones calendar.

Have someone in here experienced this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I am wrong - you have a two way sync between two contact folders, and if a contact item does have a birthday set in the source folder it also creates appointment in calendar of the source user. That appointment however is not created in the target folder.

First make sure that you use the latest version of the software - you can download it from our website: [CodeTwo Exchange Sync version history and download](http://www.codetwo.com/exchange-folder-sync/history?sts=4087)

If that is not helping - please reach our support: [codetwo.com/support](http://www.codetwo.com/support/?sts=4087)
They'll be happy to help. You can also reach me - let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: We run the latest version. Support contacted, pay as you go I was told. So wanted to see if other people had the same issue.
But yes the birthday data from the contact in the src folder is not added to the calendar when it is synced to the target users contacts.

Nope we use one way sync - 1 -> * (one to many).

Thank you.